# How can I get an element (canvas) by ID in an aspx page within the C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html5-canvas, draw

So I need to access this canvas on the aspx file. I need to make it drawable and be able to save whatever is drawn on it, also need to be able to clear it so it goes back to being white.

HTML:

```
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" runat="server"> </canvas>
</div>
```

C#:

```
if (//condition)
{
    //get canvas, resize, etc.
}
```

I've got this far.

i've tried the following:

- HTMLElement var = object.getElementById('canvas');
- using webbrowser1

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is a client-side object that requires browser code to RUN and RENDER the contents.

So, in c#, you can certainly do this:

```
if (//condition)
{
    //get canvas
    canvas.InnerHtml = "some markup here";
```

Also, in your markup, do you really think it is a good idea to have an id as the SAME name as the type of control? I mean, perhaps we need some society for the cruelty to computers here?
Using an ID with the same name as the type of the control? That is a formula for world wide mass confusing here, and will result in people winding up in a room with padded walls and going crazy.
So, with an id and runat="server" tag?

Then code behind can simply use that control (It is rendered and seen by code behind as a HtmlGenericControl).

Thus your next part of the question is to resize?

With this markup:

```
        <canvas id="mycanvas" runat="server">
        </canvas>
```

Then to resize, then you could do this in c#:

```
 mycanvas.Attributes.Add("style", "width:200px;height;200px");
```

However, for any drawing to occur in that canvas, then that will require client-side code, and not server-side code.